# Laravel - form validation on multiple options

Tags: php, laravel

Hi I've a select box (Currency) where user can select multiple currencies.

How can I have it validates each value to make sure the string min/max length are 3 and also alpha values? I tried only min/max and it thinks only allow at least 3 items and not min/max length of each value.

```
    $this->validate(request(), [
        'currencies' => 'required|array'
    ]);
```

Comment: The manual has a section about [Validating arrays](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/validation#validating-arrays)

Comment: The manual doesn't show a good example. Otherwise I won't ask here. I thought in here people will actually will help you solve instead of asking you to check manual.

Comment: Pointing you to where you can find this information in the manual is intended to be helpful and not derogatory.

Answer (score 2):

You can check `currencies` is an array of distinct values, and each value is a 3-character string like this:

```php
'currencies' => 'required|array|min:1',
'currencies.*' => 'distinct|alpha|size:3',
```

Answer (score 1):

This will check every item in `currencies` array

```
'currencies.*' => 'size:3|alpha_num'
```